# Why I am getting error, template argument required for ‘struct node’?

Tags: c++

I have written the following code to implement Linked List in C++. But I am getting the Errors on compiling it. I think the problem is with the use of Template.

```
#include<iostream>
template<class T>
struct node{
    T data;
    struct node *next;
};

template<class T>
void push(struct node **headRef ,T data){
    struct node *temp =(struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->data=data;
    temp->next=*headRef;
    *headRef=temp;
}
int main(){
    struct node *ll = NULL;
    push(&ll,10);
    push(&ll,3);
    push(&ll,6);
    push(&ll,8);
    push(&ll,13);
    push(&ll,12);
}
```

Error

```
MsLL.cpp:9:18: error: template argument required for ‘struct node’
MsLL.cpp: In function ‘void push(int**, T)’:
MsLL.cpp:10:8: error: template argument required for ‘struct node’
MsLL.cpp:10:19: error: invalid type in declaration before ‘=’ token
MsLL.cpp:10:28: error: template argument required for ‘struct node’
MsLL.cpp:10:28: error: template argument required for ‘struct node’
MsLL.cpp:10:21: error: expected primary-expression before ‘struct’
MsLL.cpp:10:21: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘struct’
MsLL.cpp:11:7: error: request for member ‘data’ in ‘temp->’, which is of non-class type ‘int’
MsLL.cpp:12:7: error: request for member ‘next’ in ‘temp->’, which is of non-class type ‘int’
MsLL.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
MsLL.cpp:16:8: error: template argument required for ‘struct node’
MsLL.cpp:16:17: error: invalid type in declaration before ‘=’ token
```

Comment: ur `node` type is a templated one, thats why. You probably want to replace `node` in the erroring locations with `node<T>`

Comment: Also, is there a compelling reason to use malloc rather than new here?

Comment: Only the `template<class T>` lines in your code can be considered C++. The rest is C. There's (almost) never a reason to write `type**` in C++.

Comment: @Praetorian Then how I will change the headRef value in the push function?

Comment: @Praetorian If a conformant C++ compiler compiles it without errors, it's C++.  (C-style C++ maybe, but C++ permits that)

Comment: @user3234277 A typical linked list implementation would have a `list<T>` class that contains a `node<T> *`. And `list<T>` would have member functions for `push`, `pop` etc. Take a look at the interface for [`std::list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In all places you write node you need to add the template arg.

```
template<class T>
struct node 
{
    T data;
    struct node *next;
};

template<class T>
void push(struct node<T> **headRef ,T data){
    struct node<T> *temp =(struct node<T>*) malloc(sizeof(struct node<T>));
    temp->data=data;
    temp->next=*headRef;
    *headRef=temp;
}
```

You should also use `new` instead of `malloc` to make sure the constructor runs on the object, using malloc can cause you grief because it just allocates a chunk of memory and does not know anything about constructors. General rule do not use malloc in C++ code if you can avoid it.

Answer (score 3):

```
struct node *ll = NULL;
```

is not valid. You have to use a template instantiation syntax.

```
struct node<int> *ll = NULL;
```

Similarly, you have to use the template parameter in `push`.

```
template<class T>
void push(struct node<T> **headRef ,T data){
    struct node<T> *temp =(struct node<T>*) malloc(sizeof(struct node<T>));
```

**Suggestions for general improvement**

1. You don't need to use `struct node<T>`. You can use just `node<T>`.
2. It's better to use `new` instead of `malloc` (and `delete` instead of `free`).

The class template can be updated to:

```
template<class T>
struct node{
    T data;
    node *next;
};
```

In `main`,

```
node<int> *ll = NULL;
```

In `push`:

```
template<class T>
void push(node<T> **headRef ,T data){
    node<T> *temp = new node<T>();
```